# How to use recyclerview smothScrollToPosition in a viewpager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, scrolltop

I use a **recyclerview** in a **viewpager** an when I want to scroll to a position using **smothScrollToPosition** I see no change in the current page but when I slide I see that the change has been applied to the next or the previous page. I have define a function in the **sliderAdapter** call **scrollTo** in this method I call **smothScrollToPosition**.The method **scrollTo** is call when the user click on a button in the **MainActivity**

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val pager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.view_pager)
    val adapter = SlideAdapter(this)

    pager.adapter = adapter

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
        adapter.scrollTo(30)
    }
}
```

}
**SlideAdapter**

```
class SlideAdapter(val context: Context) : PagerAdapter()  {

lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
lateinit var viewManager : LinearLayoutManager

fun scrollTo(position: Int) {
    viewManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 0)
}

override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean = view == `object` as RelativeLayout

override fun getCount() = 5

override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.slide, container, false) as RelativeLayout


    val list = mutableListOf<String>()

    for (i in 0..50)
        list.add("Element $i")

    val viewAdapter = Adapter(context, list)
    viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

    recyclerView.apply {
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        layoutManager = viewManager
        adapter = viewAdapter
    }

    container.addView(view)

    return view
}

override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
    container.removeView(`object` as RelativeLayout)
}
```

}

[IMAGE PAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7N2U.jpg)  I CLICK ON THE BUTTON AND I SEE NO CHANGE

[IMAGE PAGE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80aUy.jpg)  I SLIDE AND SEE THAT THE CHANGE HAS BEEN APPLIED ON THIS PAGE.

I need help please *^_^*

Answer (score 0):

From JavaDOC of method scrollToPositionWithOffset:

> Note that scroll position change will not be reflected until the next layout call.
>
> If you are just trying to make a position visible, use {@link #scrollToPosition(int)}.

May be here is the problem?